# What about a "question follow" feature?

Tags: feature-request

Since i have subscribed on SF and been active on it i have read tons of interesting questions with very interesting answers.

Those questions, and answers (i didn't ask myself), make me positively review and improve some things i have setup  in my own infrastructure (network design optimization, script improvement etc...).

Each time i read a question which i could be interested in, i have to put it in my browser favorites and come back regulary to check if it has been answered.

I think it could be interesting to add a feature that would enable to "follow" a question and be notified when there is activity on this question, e.g by using the same pin notification used for comments.

Those followed questions would appear in the user profile activity so that they could be accessed very easily from anywhere (browser favorites independent).

I am interested in your opinion about this.

Comment: This is a feature request that would be better to ask on http://meta.stackexchange.com (if it wouldn't already exist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature exist: The "favorite question", marked by the star below the question score and up/downvote arrows.

See [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: Wow yes! seems you are right, just tested it successfully. By now not sure if there are pins notifications

Comment: No, you don't get an inbox notification. See the linked meta.se question for the limitations of that feature.

Comment: @krisFR You won't get inbox notifications (and that's probably good!) but you will see notifications in your own user profile.